# Chicago_boss and redis config

Tags: redis, erlang, chicagoboss

I am looking to configure a chicago boss application for redis. I am using the eredis gem (https://github.com/wooga/eredis). Is there a way to do this from within my boss.config?

Comment: What do you mean by "Chicago Boss application for Redis"? You want to use Redis as cache?

Comment: @tkowal  Im using Redis to store data yes

Comment: where can I override the defaults eredis provides pointint to localhost etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `eredis` for caching in CB, I have bad news for you. According to [documentation](http://chicagoboss.org/api-controller.html):

```
At present only Memcached cache servers are supported,
but additional adapters will be added in the future.
```

However, if you want to use `eredis` for something else in your application, then according to [eredis docs](https://github.com/wooga/eredis/blob/master/README.md) you need to provide the details at startup:

```
To start the client, use any of the eredis:start_link/0,1,2,3,4,5 functions. They all include sensible defaults. start_link/5 takes the following arguments:

Host, dns name or ip adress as string
Port, integer, default is 6379
Database, integer or 0 for default database
Password, string or empty string([]) for no password
Reconnect sleep, integer of milliseconds to sleep between reconnect attempts
```

If you don't want to hard-code those values in the code, that starts the application, you can provide them in `boss.config`:

```
{ your_app_name, [
    {eredis_host, "some.host.name"},
    {eredis_port, 1234},
    ...
]}
```

Then, in your code, you can use `EredisHost = application:get_env(your_app_name, eredis_host)` to obtain the host name and use it during start.

Comment: @tkowal - Can we set session expiry along with cookie expiry at the same time when redis is used to store sessions?